# Powershell to return last existing folder in path

Tags: powershell

I need some help because `test-path` only returns `$true` or `$false`.

I need to return the last existing folder from $path.

```
$path = \\test.pl\power\shell\test\company
```

But the last one that exists is the `\shell` folder.

So how to get a return value like this:

```
$existingpath = \\test.pl\power\shell
$notexisting = \test\company
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attempt of solving this using the pipeline:

```
$path = '\\test.pl\power\shell\test\company'

# Create an array that consists of the full path and all parents
$pathAndParents = for( $p = $path; $p; $p = Split-Path $p ) { $p }

# Find the first existing path
$existingPath = $pathAndParents | Where-Object { Test-Path $_ } | Select-Object -First 1

# Extract the non-existing part of the path
$nonExistingPath = $path.SubString( $existingPath.Length + 1 )
```

The `for` loop creates a temporay variable `$p` so the original path will not be destroyed. At each iteration it outputs variable `$p`, which is automatically added to the array, due to PowerShell's implicit output behaviour. Then it sets `$p` to the parent path of `$p` (`Split-Path` with a single unnamed argument returns the parent path). The loop exits when there is no parent anymore.

The `Where-Object | Select-Object` line may seem inefficent, but because of `Select-Object` argument `-First 1` it actually tests only the necessary number of paths. When the first existing path is found, the pipeline will be exited (like a `break` statement in a loop).

---

The above was the accepted answer. The following solution has been added later. It is more efficient, because it calls `Split-Path` only as many times as necessary and doesn't need `Where-Object` and `Select-Object`.

```
$path = '\\test.pl\power\shell\test\company'

# Find the first existing path
for( $existingPath = $path; 
     $existingPath -and -not (Test-Path $existingPath);
     $existingPath = Split-Path $existingPath ) {}

# Extract the non-existing part of the path
$nonExistingPath = $path.SubString( $existingPath.Length + 1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check each folder path one by one, using `Split-Path`, `Test-Path` and a `while` loop:

```
$path = '.\test.pl\power\shell\test\company'

# Check folder at current path
while(-not(Test-Path $path)){
  # Move on to the parent folder
  $path = $path |Split-Path
}

# $path will now be `'.\test.pl\power\shell'`
$path
```

Comment: You have an endless loop when no part of `$path` exists and `$path` does not start with a `.` (e. g. a full path).

Comment: This can indeed cause an infinite loop; the path should ideally be resolved first, and then the root of this checked before the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Further to the first answer, it is preferable to resolve and test the root of the passed path before processing:

```
$path = '\\test.pl\power\shell\test\company'
$resolvedPath = $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($path)

$root = Split-Path $resolvedPath -Qualifier
if (Test-Path $root -PathType Container) {
    while (-not (Test-Path $resolvedPath -PathType Container)) {
        $resolvedPath = Split-Path $resolvedPath
    }
} else {
    $resolvedPath = ''
}
$resolvedPath
```

Or using .NET methods:

```
$root = [System.IO.Path]::GetPathRoot($resolvedPath)
if ([System.IO.Directory]::Exists($root)) {
    while (-not [System.IO.Directory]::Exists($resolvedPath)) {
        $resolvedPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($resolvedPath)
    }
} else {
    $resolvedPath = ''
}
$resolvedPath
```